# filtrar variables de tweets

Tags: python, sql

se pueden filtrar los tweets (recolectados en una lista de diccionarios) por algunas variables?

Esta es la salida

```
{'statuses': [{'created_at': 'Fri Dec 06 00:39:33 +0000 2019',
   'id': 1202749383332286464,
   'id_str': '1202749383332286464',
   'text': 'RT @FLagos_Neumann: He recibido amenazas y muy violentas. Incluso contra mi vida. Eso no me va a silenciar. Seguire ejerciendo mi derecho d…',
   'truncated': False,
   'entities': {'hashtags': [],
    'symbols': [],
    'user_mentions': [{'screen_name': 'FLagos_Neumann',
      'name': 'Florencia Lagos Neumann',
      'id': 387725299,
      'id_str': '387725299',
      'indices': [3, 18]}], ...}
```

Tengo el siguiente código para editar.

```
f = 'datos.txt'
with open(f,'rb') as rfp: 
        lista_tweets = pickle.load(rfp)
        # carga lista de tweets
for x in response_dict['statuses']:
    lista_tweets.append(x)
    #agrega los tweets de la nueva busqueda a la lista
with open(f,'wb') as wfp:
    pickle.dump(lista_tweets, wfp)
    # guarda nueva lista
with open(f,'rb') as rfp:
    lista_tweets = pickle.load(rfp)
    # carga la lista
```

que comandos se pueden usar para filtrar la búsqueda y guardar solo por ejemplo las 'id' y el 'texto'.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Crea un nuevo diccionario que contenga solo las dos claves que buscas. Por ejemplo así:

```
for x in response_dict['statuses']:
    lista_tweets.append({"id": x["id"], "text": x["text"] })
```

Si quieres ser más flexible y general, puedes hacer una función que extraiga los campos que le pasas como parámetro. Por ejemplo así:

```
def extraer_campos(data, campos):
   return { campo: data.get(campo, None) for campo in campos }
```

Esta función utiliza lo que se llama una *dict comprehension* para crear en una sola línea un diccionario a base de iterar por las claves que vienen en el parámetro `campos`. En lugar de `data[campo]`, que podría haber usado, he elegido en cambio `data.get(campo, None)` que hace lo mismo con la ventaja de que si el campo no está presente en `data`, en lugar de romper con una excepción te devolverá `None` (o lo que especifiques como segundo parámetro de `data.get()`).

Con esa función tu bucle quedaría:

```
for x in response_dict['statuses']:
    lista_tweets.append(extraer_campos(x, ["id", "text"]))
```